# selecting row from one table and insert into other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Selecting rows from table1 which do not exists in table2 and inserting it in table2

like

**Images**

```
id  type    name
502  1      summer.gif
```

**SEOImages**

```
id      idimage ... ...
1000    501     ... ...
```

Now I want to select all the rows from `Images` table whose id does not match idimage `SEOImages` table and insert those rows into the `SEOImages` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach :**

```
Insert into Table2
select A,B,C,....
  from Table1
 Where Not Exists (select * 
                 from table2 
                where Your_where_clause)
```

**Example :**

[**SQLFiddelDemo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a527d/2)

```
Create table Images(id int,
                    type int,
                    name varchar(20));
Create table SEOImages(id int,
                       idimage int);

insert into Images values(502,1,'Summer.gif');
insert into Images values(503,1,'Summer.gif');
insert into Images values(504,1,'Summer.gif');
insert into SEOImages values(1000,501);
insert into SEOImages values(1000,502);
insert into SEOImages values(1000,503);

insert into SEOImages
select 1000,id
  from Images I
 where not exists (select * 
                  from SEOImages
                  where idimage =I.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO SeoImages
(IdImage)
SELECT ID
FROM Images
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT IDIMAGE FROM SEOImages)
```

Answer (score 1):

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM Images
  WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT idimage FROM SEOImages)
```

should bring out those rows from Images that do not have a corresponding ID in SEOImages, assuming they are both of the same type.

Alternatively, using a JOIN:

```
SELECT i.* FROM Images i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SEOImages s on i.id = s.imageId
WHERE s.imageId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO SEOImages
SELECT *
FROM Images
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM Images t1, SEOImages t2 
                 WHERE t1.id=t2.id) ;
```